# 'Element' 'BackupSchedule' from namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure' is not expected. Expecting element 'BackupName'

Tags: c#, azure, web-applications

I am using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Websites library version 1.7.1-preview. When calling to update backup configuration a wepapp, the exception thrown from api (Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException) with message like the title.
Here the code looks like:

```
public async Task AddBackupsAsync(Guid subscriptionId, string resourceGroupName, string webSiteName, string storageUrl, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var client = GetWebsiteClient(subscriptionId);
        var schedule = new BackupSchedule
        {
            FrequencyInterval = 1,
            FrequencyUnit = FrequencyUnit.Day,
            RetentionPeriodInDays = 35,
            KeepAtLeastOneBackup = true
        };

        var request = new BackupRequest(name: webSiteName)
        {
            BackupSchedule = schedule,
            StorageAccountUrl = storageUrl,
            Enabled = true
        };

        await client.WebApps.UpdateBackupConfigurationAsync(resourceGroupName, webSiteName, request, cancellationToken);
    }
```

The exception just come recently though we don't change anything related to api version. 
Anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: What exception are you facing?

Comment: It is Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException with message the same question's title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sound like the parameter missing BackupRequestName property